# Generate CSV file client side, send using Angular POST, save server side through PHP backend

Tags: php, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

situation:
clients has an existing windows app that uses csv files to transfer data back and forth and wants to persist in that manner.

challenge:
After reading CSV data from server address process the data and generate a new CSV file and upload this to the 'backend'.

What I have tried:
I have read just about every SO post on uploading files, but the problem is that if i just use the test data. I.e. read the file, rename and save to backend it doesn't seem to work?

I use below code to get the blob for the file, this works fine and I can manipulate the data after retrieving it:

```
getCsvData3(url: string) {
        let httpOptions: any = {
            //observe: 'response',
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }),
            params: new HttpParams(),
            responseType: 'response'
        }
                     
        return this.httpClient.get<string>(url, httpOptions);
    }
```

Now I tried testing this by simply re-creating a `File` object and attach it to the outgoing process.
Using:

```
const type = { type: data.body.type };
const blob = new Blob([data.body], type);
const file = this.blobToFile(blob, 'test.csv')
```

Where `blobToFile` looks like (I have tried several options to do this to no avail):

```
blobToFile(theBlob: Blob, fileName: string): File {
        var b: any = theBlob;
        //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
        b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
        b.name = fileName;

        //Cast to a File() type
        return <File>theBlob;
    }
```

Subsequently I attach the file to the `httpClient.Post()` call:

```
uploadFile(file: File, fileNum: number) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("the_file", file, file.name);
        this.dataService.uploadWithProgress(formData)
            .subscribe(event => {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                    console.log(Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total));
                    //let percentUploaded = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log(file.name + ', Size: ' + file.size + ', Uploaded URL: ' +         event.body.link);
                    //this.fileUploadSuccess();
                }
            },
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
```

But no matter what I try, I do not get this to work?

I have also tried to use the MediaFilePicker of NativeScript but that too gives all sorts of nightmares?
See this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a NativeScript core app that uploads a JSON file and is received/processed by a small PHP file on the host.  You can ignore the authentication code, and you'll have to convert to Angular, but this should at least serve as a working example:

```
/**
* Post app's eventData object to the web, so that it may live-update apps in the field. 
* Uses basic authentication; requires .htaccess and .htpasswd files in host directory
* @param {object} eventData - app's event-specific data object, from event-data.js
* @return void
*/
exports.postEventData = function (eventData) {

  dialogs.confirm({
    title: "myutils.postEventData",
    message: "Post app's eventData object to web?",
    okButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No"
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result) { // if Yes selected

      let content = JSON.stringify(eventData);

      http.request({
        url: eventData.subdomain + eventData.postPath, // path to receive.php
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "Authorization": "Basic " + credentials,
        },
        content: content
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.content.toString());
        dialogs.alert({
          title: "myutils.postEventData",
          message: "EventData posted successfully.",
          okButtonText: "OK"
        }).then(() => { return; });
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        dialogs.alert({
          title: "myutils.postEventData",
          message: "EventData post failed. \n\n " + err,
          okButtonText: "OK"
        }).then(() => { return; });
      }); // end http.request
    } // end Yes selected
  }); // end confirm.then 
} // end postEventData
```

And here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Receive json file via http POST request and save contents to current directory.   
 * @author David Cole <dlcole33@gmail.com>
 */

  if (empty($_POST) && empty($_GET)) { // Both POST and GET arrays should be empty 
    $outputFilename = "eventData.json";
    $outputFile = getcwd() . "/" . $outputFilename;
    $fileData = file_get_contents('php://input');
       
    $fp = fopen($outputFile, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $fileData);
    fclose($fp);
    
    if (file_exists ( $outputFile )) {
      echo "File " . $outputFile . " created on host.\n";
    } else {
      echo "File " . $outputFile . " creation failed.\n";
    }
    // echo $fileData;
  } else {
    echo '$_POST / $_GET check failed.\n';
  }
  exit();
?>
```

Comment: many thanks. Your file however doesn't seem to upload an actual <File> object? It appears that you convert your 'content' into a JSON object and attach that as a formData field to the post call. In your post call you retrieve that object and create the actual file in the PHP script (that is the fwrite($fp, $fileData); line). A file object on PHP will be handled by the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] object? So, in short, you send JSON data and create the file on the PHP server, you do not create the file at the client and send the file...

Comment: I'm not sure of the distinction you're making. Data is data, yes?  If you upload the .csv file contents and receive it via PHP, have you not accomplished what you want?

Comment: many thanks for your reply and no that is not the same. If I were to send data i.e. value = 3 for example I can send that as a JSON object = { 'value': 3 } if I `POST` that to a server the server can then create a file (with a name, size, latestModified property) and save that locally. In that case I send the data. What I would like to do is create the file (at the client) and then 'upload' or `POST` the file. The distinction would be that the file could be a PDF, an Excel file or a CSV, where as in your example you send just the raw data and create the file server side.

Comment: This may -in the case of small amount of data- yield the same result (i.e. your data is on the server in a file) but the method is distinctly different. You can argue on whether this method is the ideal way to do this -which is a valid though different topic- but for the moment I am bound by the conditions that are set by my client

Comment: I understand your point.  Sounds like HTTP PUT may be what you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. But also no, a `PUT` request is also not the solution. `PUT` requests are similar to `POST` with one difference is that `POST` should be used to create 'new' data where `PUT` should be used to update data.
https://www.keycdn.com/support/put-vs-post